# Drupal 7 VBO's hook form_alter doesn't trigger

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, hook

I'm using the [View Bulk Operation](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module to do a multiple delete on my custom view where I list my contents.

But I have to check a value to know whether I accept to delete a content or not...
I've managed to do it with the multiple selection on my `/admin/content` view with the `hook_form_alter()` BUT it doesn't trigger when I do this on my custom view ...

I've tried other hooks like :

- `hook_views_bulk_operations_form_alter()` which sounded nice ... But it doesn't trigger at all
- `hook_node_delete()` could have worked but I have no idea how to stop the delete process when in the function (`exit;` or `break;` just throw an error and I don't get why)

My code of the hook_form_later which work fine with the 'content page' :

```
function MODULE-NAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  foreach($form['nodes'] as $pnode)
  {
    if(is_array($pnode))
    {
        if(!isDeletable($pnode['#value'])) // my function which says if we can delete the content
        {
            $n = node_load($pnode['#value']);
            $status = isset($n->workbench_moderation['current']->state) ? $n->workbench_moderation['current']->state : false;
            $string = "This content won't be deleted : ".substr($pnode['#suffix'],0,-6); // substr to cut off the '</li>' !
            drupal_set_message(t($string), 'warning');

            unset($form['nodes'][''.$pnode['#value']]); // get the content off the form ( my way to say that the content shouldn't be deleted )
        }
    }
  }
}
```

How does `hook_views_bulk_operations_form_alter()` trigger ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think VBO has its own form alter hook, so `hook_views_bulk_operations_form_alter()` simply isn't called.

The way I've been doing it is by using `hook_form_alter()`, similar to your solution, but with a check on the form ID to only act on the VBO forms I'm interested in.

Theoretically you could add a an alter hook on VBO forms, but I think it would be slower than implementing directly in `hook_form_alter()`. If you have a lot of VBO forms to modify it *might* be worth it, though.